# Set Connection String of DataSet.xsd based on User Setting

Tags: c#, xsd, dataset, database-connection

#### Situation

I have a C# program that utilizes a DataSet.xsd for displaying sales data in a window. Everything currently works but the Connection String that the DataSet.xsd uses is hardcoded to an .accdb file and I would like it to be a dynamic assignment.

#### Problem

The specific file path of the database can be changed in the user settings, which leads to a path issue with the sales window. The Connection String is currently being grabbed from a User Setting in the program.

[image: 1]

#### Question

The `C:\FITS\FITS3SR\FITS_7.accdb` segment is the path that could be changed by the user. Is there a way to programitcally or dynamically change this connection string?

Comment: Is the path always the same?

Comment: @stuartd No, the path can be whatever the user desires. It's usually not too much different for each client computer, but I'm trying to steer clear of hardcoded file paths that can be changed. I also am trying to bring down the amount of small tweaks we need to make on the solution for each office that decides to take on our program.

Comment: If your program uses an installer, you may be be able to get the path like in [this question](http://superuser.com/a/1024129/1388)

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not use an installer. I'm also not entirely following how that post would apply to a DataSet Connection String, though.

Comment: So the connection string isn't pointing to the installed location? Because before you can set the connection string dynamically, you need to know where it's going to point to.

Comment: No it's not set to the installed location. It's set to whatever location the user specifies in the settings. And that setting can be changed after installation. That .accdb file is generated every week from something else and is placed in a specific location that the user chooses after installation. That's the problem. I would need to be able to set it programatically based on the path chosen by the user.

Comment: Ah, I see. Can you record the location the user selects?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround for it. Because the Connection String was forced to be an Application Setting, it was set as a Read Only setting by default and I was under the impression that it could not be edited. Fortunately, I was able to change the value of the Application Setting at runtime by using the following line:

```
Properties.Settings.Default["SettingName"] = "connection string goes here";
```

Hope this helps someone else.